# Safe area not working in custom TabBarController's ViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of my app's AppDelegate, after initializing my UIWindow property, I set the root controller to a subclass of UITabBarController, in which I set the view controllers (and some other custom behaviour).

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = TabBarController() // a subclass of UITabBarController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

The issue I have is that the safe areas in the TabBarController's view controllers does not seem to work properly.

eg: sticking a view to the bottom of a view controller's view, using it's safeAreaLayoutGuide, goes behind the tab bar.

```
self.bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
```

The custom behaviour (such as set tint colors, set the viewControllers and their tab bar items, or set the tabBarController's delegate - nothing crazy here) setup is made in it's `viewDidLoad`.

NB: I work in code only, I do not use interface builder.

Comment: "Am I missing something" Yes, but I don't know what it is because I can't reproduce what you're describing. On my machine, a subview pinned to the bottom of the safe area in the child of a tab bar controller appears above the tab bar, just as one would expect, in iOS 13, iOS 12, or whatever.

Comment: If you want your view to stick with superview's bottom, you don't need to consider the safeAreaLayoutGuide, pin directly with view.bottomAnchor

Comment: @matt I simply add the view to it's superview in the viewDidLoad, and I initialize the view controller in my UITabBarController's init in it's viewControllers property. I don't feel like I'm doing anything weird here...

Comment: @GauravChandarana I have the exact same result by setting my constraint to safeAreaLayoutGuide's bottom and the view's bottom.

Comment: @GauravChandarana Everything you're saying is bogus. Please stop misleading the OP.

Comment: @Que20 If you knew whether you were doing anything weird, you wouldn't have a question. That's what a question _is_, it means there is something you don't know. See my answer. Unlike you, I've actually shown my code.

Comment: @GauravChandarana Ok, so what should I do ?

Comment: @matt, can you please explain why did you find it bogus?

Comment: @matt I just edited the question to add more code, but as I say in the question, I'm not sure what piece of my code should be shown as it's pretty basic.

Comment: Well it hardly matters. I showed you _all_ of _my_ code, my code doesn't misbehave, and one counterexample is sufficient to disprove the hypothesis.

Comment: And you are still not showing enough code. How do I know, from what you showed, that you remembered to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`?

Comment: @matt I did, and you're right, I'll add the UIView subclass's code used as `bottomView`.

Comment: Also, presenting the view out of the UITabBarConttroler (from the app delegate, as I'm not using IB), works fine. Maybe I did something wrong in the TabBarController ?

Comment: I substituted your code for mine (in my FirstViewController) and I still see exactly what we expect to see.

Comment: I feel like the problem does not come from the constraint, and more the way I use the Tab Bar Controller... The question's title does not feel good.
What did you have in mind @GauravChandarana ?

Comment: I found the issue by putting the TabBarController in a NavigationController. More on the answer I posted above.
Thank you for your answers and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the way I presented programmatically the tab bar controller.
What I did in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` was :

```
    self.window?.rootViewController = MyTabBarController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I fixed the issue buy putting the tabbar in in a NavigationController :

```
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyTabBarController())
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: That's not useful. In the first place, nothing in the question told us you have subclassed UITabBarController (which is never a good thing to do). In the second place, nothing about the answer explains what you were doing wrong originally.

Comment: I agree. I don’t know how I’m supposed to turn the question to make it « useful ». And I mentioned the UITabBarController in my first comment replying to yours. I might just delete the question.

Comment: I wouldn’t object but it would be more useful to track this down.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce. Here's the *complete* code for a view controller in a project that does what you seem to describe:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(v)
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

And here's the result; the red square appears exactly where we expect to see it, pinned to the top of the tab bar:

[image]